# How to alloc memory manually

Tags: c, pointers

When I was studying pointer, I had an idea to get a better view about the 
memory allocation, so I tried to allocate memory manually to the pointer,
but it didn't work.
Can someone explain more about it? I didn't find anything.

I wrote some C code, this code allocates a pointer and prints the positions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *test;
    test = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    test[0] = 't';
    test[1] = 'e';
    test[2] = 's';
    test[3] = 't';
    test[4] = ' ';
    test[5] = ' ';
    test[6] = ' ';
    test[7] = ' ';
    printf("%p\n",test);
    printf("%p\n",test[0]);
    printf("%p\n",test[1]);
    printf("%p\n",test[2]);
    printf("%p\n",test[3]);
    printf("%p\n",test[4]);
    printf("%p\n",test[5]);
    printf("%p\n",test[6]);
    printf("%p\n",test[7]);
}
```

when i execute it the output was this
and only the first line changes, on the executions

```
0x561160
0x74
0x65
0x73
0x74
0x20
0x20
0x20
0x20
```

So write this other

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        char *memory;
        memory = malloc(1);
//        memory = 0x561160;
        memory[0] = 0x74;
        memory[1] = 0x65;
        memory[2] = 0x73;
        memory[3] = 0x74;
        memory[4] = 0x72;
        memory[5] = 0x20;
        memory[6] = 0x20;
        memory[7] = 0x20;
        printf("%s",memory);
}
```

if I allocate the memory, the program gets the output 'test   ' (so ok)

But if I use the commented memory position (that I get from the other program), the program crashes, someone can tell me why the program crashes if I didn't free the other pointer?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall  -Wextra` is pretty good for *gcc* and *clang*), that should tell you what's wrong with your first program. Also, of you want to bypass malloc, you still need to get the memory from the OS, you can't "just use" any memory, it us Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: but i used the memory that the program allocate to me in the first program, i dont free this memory, yeah like to use -Wall too, but i like to test the warnings.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char*))` allocates memory for _one_ pointer (4 or 8 bytes depending on your platform). `malloc(1)` allocates memory for a single byte. Think about it.

Comment: If you do ```memory = malloc(1);```, then its dangerous to use an index on the resulting pointer that is bigger than the size you allocated. Ie for ```memory = malloc(1);``` it is not valid to access at ```memory[1], memory[2] .... etc```. For ```malloc(sizeof(char*))``` that would depend on the size of a pointer on your machine and compiler.

Comment: `printf("%p\n",test[0])` is plain wrong. You probably want `printf("%p\n",&test[0])` or `printf("%i\n",test[0])` or `printf("%c\n",test[0])`.

Comment: Malloc'ing is not just getting a legal address for your process, but also making enough room for what you are going to store in it. In both cases you don't malloc enough memory: in the first you get 4 bytes (char * size), but you are writing 8 bytes.

Comment: When you invoke Undefined Behaviour (such as accessing memory that is not allocated for you, using wrong format specifier in `printf`, both of which you do), you can't really reason about your C code any more or "understand what is going on" at C level. The behaviour is literally undefined. It allows for what you expect, crash, security exploit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a program (a *process*) on modern operating system, it gets its own address space.  That address space exists for the duration of the process, but it cleaned up when the process finishes.  Furthermore, different processes' address spaces are completely isolated from each other.

With this, you can't simply take a pointer printed by a program and then simply use it in a different process.

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_management_(computing)

A separate issue is that neither of your two examples allocates enough storage for `memory`.

Comment: i understood know now... so why is good practice to use free in all the pointers variables  ?

Comment: @Calisto: It's a guideline, but not strictly a requirement (provided, of course, that excessive memory consumption doesn't cause other issues).  It is not that uncommon to see long-lived structures getting allocated at the program start (or when they're first needed) and then just left hanging around and never freed explicitly.

Comment: so why i can use the first program content ?
remember what i said? i used the positions memory in the second program, and the content from the first was pulled to the second

Comment: my big doubt is...why when i use the position memory 
the program crashes
being that var and var[0] its the same

Comment: @Calisto because each process has their own memory and addresses are *virtual*, not physical. One process’ 0x12345678 has nothing to do with other process’ 0x12345678. The address might not exist at all. Read about memory management, virtual memory, paging etc.

Comment: ok! thanks. you helped me so much.
one more question, the last.
Why are the memory position of bytes shared by processes?

Comment: if i allocate the  pointer memory, so i can use the extern process memory normally.
like in my example, i can get the string 'test' that i created in a extern process